# Selenium, Python - Use For-loop in finding values in a column, but resulted in duplicating first values instead

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, html-table, static

[image]

Above is the practice website I am attempting to extract only the name column. However, from my For-loop, I am repeatedly accounting the name Alan five times (see img below). Unfortunately, my For-loop counted the header row too as row 0.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#Scenario a HTML table is provided
#Feature: HTML table
def test_table():
    URL = 'https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/tag/table.html'

    #Given website loaded a table <--The Set Up
    b=webdriver.Chrome()
    b.get(URL)
    wait=WebDriverWait(b,20)

    #When user arrives at the website and sees a table <-- IGNORE, when print text, all values are correct.
    table=b.find_element(By.ID,'mytable')

    #Then the table shows a column of names <-- The issue
    rows=b.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'tr')
    for i, col in enumerate(rows):
        col=b.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'td').text
        print(f'Row: {i}, Name: {row}')

    
    b.quit()

test_table()
```

Result:

[image]

I had thought of using the expected condition, but the table is static. Which led to me deciding that the use of expected condition wasn't necessary. Also, I had considered that the tag name wasn't used correctly, but this wasn't the case. Any assistant is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are traversing the whole page instead of just the rows. And since you are searching for single element in the loop, it returns the first `td` element of the page. It should be

```
for i, col in enumerate(rows):
  name = col.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'td').text
  print(f'Row: {i}, Name: {name}')
```